# Old series about a normal boy getting super powers

Tags: story-identification

About 20-30 years ago I watched a series where a normal boy got superpowers. I'm wondering which series that was?

The facts that I remember are:

- His neighbour was sorta strange I think a scientist (mad) and was responsible for empowering him accidently.
- His powers were few. He only got 1 in the first season and another one in the second (I think the first one was to hover/fly).
- He had a little sister who was sort of a nuisance.
- His family had a dog.
- It was translated into german even (so not english only, but also a german adaption).

  - If I remember it correctly the title of the series had something to do with "hero"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the series '[My Secret Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Secret_Identity)', which ran from 1988 to 1991.

- His neighbor was, indeed, a 'mad scientist' type
- Initially, he gains super speed, invulnerability and the ability to levitate, but he ends up having to use spray cans to control his 'flight' while levitating.
- In season two, he can suddenly control his flight without the cans (never explained, as I recall.)
- Later, her gains super strength, at the cost of his invulnerability.
- He did have a sister (played by Marsha Moreau), and I believe a dog as well.

I believe the German title was "Ultraman - Mein Geheimes Ich"
**Note** This is the translated version; if it was also adapted into another show, I haven't found it yet.

Here's (while it remains up) the opening from Season 1, and a much clearer opening from Season 3

Comment: 'Yepp that was it as soon as I read the cans I knew it was it (remembered it as readig that the cans were needed^^, had forgotten about his speed though)